# OpenCv version 3 some python bindings missing?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have been messing around with Opencv in python, and noticed that a lot methods don't seem to exist.

For example:

```
cv2.NormalBayesClassifier
```

fails (python says that there is no module called this)

How can I get these methods working? Do I have to revert to opencv version 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have immediately found it after posting.

It seems to be under

```
cv2.ml.NormalBayesClassifier_create()
```

right now, which is a bit confusing. For some reason the naming conventions seem to change for every method in every version.

Comment: The update from CV2.4.X to CV3.0 was quite a big one, that's probably why you find so many changes.